# CPU running High after 2 hours of use

Tags: c#, sockets, server, tcp, .net-4.8

I'm working on a c# framework 4.8 project which has a number of tcp sockets (+/-20) waiting for data. When I start the project everything is fine and it receives like 10 packets a minute.

CPU is low round 10%

When the program runs for like 2 hours the CPU rises to 40-50% even when no data is received.

I've attached the remote debugger and discovered the Garbage Collector is collecting like Crazy. After profiling the CPU the Hotpath ends in System.Configuration.Dll.

Can anybody tell me what the system.configuration.dll has to do with sockets and how to fix this?[image]

```
public class TcpConnectionState: ConnectionStateBase, IConnectionState
{
    private byte[] _buffer;
    private Socket _socket;
    private ReceiveCallbackDelegate _receiveCallback;

    public IPEndPoint Endpoint => (IPEndPoint)_socket.RemoteEndPoint;

    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TcpConnectionState(ILogger<TcpConnectionState> logger, Socket socket, byte[] buffer, IDevice device, ReceiveCallbackDelegate receiveCallback, DisconnectCallbackDelegate disconnectCallback):
        base(device, disconnectCallback)
    {
        _logger = Validate.IsNotNull(logger, nameof(logger));

        _socket = socket;
        _buffer = buffer;
        _receiveCallback = receiveCallback;

        BeginReceive();
    }

    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            return !(_socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && _socket.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException) 
        { 
            return false; 
        }
    }

    private void BeginReceive()
    {
        try
        {
            _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, BeginReceiveCallback, null);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void BeginReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesReceived = _socket.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                var data = _buffer.Take<byte>(bytesReceived).ToArray<byte>();

                _receiveCallback(data, null, _socket.RemoteEndPoint);
            }
            BeginReceive();
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(ex.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, string.Empty);
            }
            
            Disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, string.Empty);
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
    
    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, BeginSendCallback, null);
            _logger.LogTrace(data, d => $"Send {BitConverter.ToString(d)}");
            _logger.LogDebug($"Sent {data.Length} bytes");
        }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(ex.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, string.Empty);
            }

            Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, string.Empty);
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void BeginSendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
            var bytesSent = _socket.EndSend(ar);
    }

    public override void Disconnect()
    {
        _socket.BeginDisconnect(false, BeginDisconnectCallback, null);
    }

    private void BeginDisconnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Disconnect");

        base.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: "discovered the Garbage Collector is collecting like Crazy" are you creating objects on the fly at a short interval?

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Which kind of project is this? web or desktop? maybe the problem is in the way the socket is being injected, also if you are using a self-hosted signalR and you are sure the problem is related to the socket you could migrate to AzureSignalR, that way your socket will be running in a different instance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-overview

Comment: @MongZhu no when no data is received no objects are created

Comment: @sebrojas it is a windows service so basicly a console application

Comment: Ok so i've added a Log when bytes received == 0 and this is run in a loop. after further reading when a device gracefully disconnects the socket the endreceive is called without any data. Why does it only happen after 2 hours IDK. So i think i should mark as disconnected when receiving 0 bytes.